# Cannot connect to FTP on Gingerbread

Tags: android, ftp

I recently noticed that when trying to run my application on the Gingerbread emulation, that FTP broke. I am currently using the apache commons external library for FTP support, but for some reason it works on every other Android OS except 2.3 (Gingerbread)

Here is my FTP code

```
FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.connect(SERVER);
ftp.login("anonymous", "anonymous");
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

InputStream is = ftp.retrieveFileStream("file.txt");
byte[] data = new byte[1024];

fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int x = 0;
while((x=is.read(data,0,1024))>=0){
    fos.write(data,0,x);
}
fos.flush();
fos.close();
ftp.logout();
ftp.disconnect();
```

As I said, this is tested and works on 1.6, 2.1 and 2.2, but not 2.3. I've tried all day to figure out why and how to fix it but I can't find any solution.

I was therefore wondering if anybody have experience with FTP and Gingerbread and if you might be so nice to guide me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it get past authentication?   Are any exceptions being thrown?

Comment: Your code works OK for me with Android 2.3.1 API level 9 emulator and the commons-net-2.0.jar. Perhaps you have an older version? I used FTP site www.mirrorservice.org and the file /pub/gnu/r.README

Comment: What is failing? do you have a stacktrace? failing to build or failing to run?

Comment: It seems that FTP does work on a real phone, but not in the emulator of gingerbread. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the problem, but I found out that FTP on Android 2.3 does work, but not in emulation.

The moment I tried my code on my cell phone, it worked like it had on all previous versions of Android.

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is if you have the correct permissions, if that is the case check Logcat for any exceptions. If you have any please post them here or via a pastebin.